# How to choose directory name during untarring

Tags: rename, tar

Say I have a file named `ugly_name.tar`, which when extracted, becomes `ugly_name` directory. What command can I use so that the resulting directory name is `pretty_name` instead?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

This should work:

```
mkdir pretty_name && tar xf ugly_name.tar -C pretty_name --strip-components 1
```

`-C` changes to the specified directory before unpacking (or packing). `--strip-components` removes the specified number of directories from the filenames stored in the archive.

Note that this is not really portable. GNU tar and at least some of the BSD tars have the `--strip-components` option, but doesn't seem to exist on other unix-like platforms.

The dumb way of doing this would work pretty much everywhere though.

```
tar xf ugly_name.tar && mv ugly_name pretty_name
```

Comment: I think I'll stick with the dumb version :)

Comment: @phunehehe: one advantage of the smart version is u don't have to know in advance what the untarred directory name is

Comment: May I add, that this works for more than "Pretty_name". You can also untar to a specific directory this way. Example: `tar -xvf /tmp/backupfiles.tar -C /var/www/`

Comment: On Rasbian it is `--strip`

Comment: I usually use the dumb way, and I use wildcards in case I don't know what the ugly name will be or I don't want to write it down.  `mv ugly-* pretty_name`

Comment: @DavidGrayson Wildcards had completely slipped my mind, thank you!

Comment: Dumb way doesn't work if there's already an ``ugly_name`` directory. By the way, beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: I get a `tar: could not chdir to 'pretty_name'` error, but extracting without renaming works.

Answer (score 40):

With [GNU tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) ≥1.16, use [`--transform`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC113) to apply a sed regexp transformation to each file name (the transformation is applied on the full path in the archive):

```
tar xf foo.tar --transform 's!^ugly_name\($\|/\)!pretty_name\1!'
```

If `ugly_name` is the toplevel component of all the file names in the archive, you don't need to bother with precise matching:

```
tar xf foo.tar --transform 's/ugly_name/pretty_name/'
```

If you don't know the name of the toplevel directory, you can still use this method, though you might prefer [`--strip-components`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring/11019#11019) instead.

```
tar xf foo.tar --transform 's!^[^/]\+\($\|/\)!pretty_name\1!'
```

With [`pax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/pax.html), the POSIX archive utility, use the `-s` option, which takes a sed-like replacement expression as an argument.

```
pax -rf foo.tar -s '!^ugly_name\($\|/\)!pretty_name\1!'
pax -rf foo.tar -s '/ugly_name/pretty_name/'
pax -rf foo.tar -s '!^[^/]\+\($\|/\)!pretty_name\1!'
```

Answer (score 21):

Simplest way

```
tar xvf dml/ugly_name.tar --one-top-level=pretty_name --strip-components 1
```

Comment: (1) This is clearly not the simplest way, as [smac89 posted an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11018/80216#448326) featuring ``--one-top-level=pretty_name`` without ``--strip-components 1``.  (2) Conversely, [the accepted answer (posted by Mat)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11018/80216#11019) features `--strip-components 1` without `--one-top-level=pretty_name`.  (3) Can you explain why your answer, combining these options, is better than any of the older ones? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: maybe a real example may help you clarify:
`
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.23-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xvf mysql-5.7.23-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64.tar.gz --one-top-level=mysql57 --strip-components 1
`

Comment: This answer is more elegant than [the one with the most upvote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring/11019#11019).

Comment: @G-Man `--strip-component 1` is required, with either the `mkdir` or `--strip-components 1` method, otherwise you just get `pretty_name/ugly_name/`.

Comment: This is indeed the simplest way

Comment: `--one-top-level` unrecognized option for `tar (GNU tar) 1.26`

Answer (score 12):

Use this :

```
tar -xvf ugly_name.tar
mv ugly_name pretty_name
```

Comment: You may prefer to use `&&` list operator between those two commands, so the second get executed only if the first one succeeded.

Comment: This could have undesirable consequences if a directory `ugly_name` already exists.

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit

As pointed out in the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring/448326#comment1008034_448326), this method does not work for archives that are properly formed, however as [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470421/44793) shows, you should add `--strip-components 1` for this to really work. I have tested with this new option and it works both for archives with a top-level name and ones without.

---

#### Original answer

From askUbuntu, this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1018374/145907) worked for me:

```
tar zxvf ugly_name.tgz --one-top-level=pretty_name
```

> **`--one-top-level[=dir]'**
>
> Tells tar to create a new directory beneath
>   the extraction directory (or the one passed to `-C') and use it to
>   guard against tarbombs. In the absence of dir argument, the name of
>   the new directory will be equal to the base name of the archive (file
>   name minus the archive suffix, if recognized). Any member names that
>   do not begin with that directory name (after transformations from
>   `--transform' and `--strip-components') will be prefixed with it.
>   Recognized file name suffixes are `.tar', and any compression suffixes
>   recognizable by See [-auto-compress](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Option-Summary.html#g_t_002d_002dauto_002dcompress).

Comment: The issue with this is that it doesn't rename the top level directory, instead it creates a new level, named `pretty_name`, with the original top-level directory inside that. E.g. if `tar xzf ugly_name.tgz` would create a directory called `ugly_name/`, then the command you've provided would create `pretty_name/ugly_name/`.

Comment: @davidA Good point. I have updated my answer to include a fix for this