# Extract tar.gz file to the same filename

Tags: shell-script, tar

I tried to extract `filename1.tar.gz` but I got the different name which is the folder archive inside lets say `archive_folder`; how I can extract the `tar.gz` with the same name of the filename.

I use this command:

```
tar -xzvf filename1.tar.gz
```

also I want to write a command to extract multiple `tar.gz` with one line.

Comment: Duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose directory name during untarring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/how-to-choose-directory-name-during-untarring)

Comment: No,I need the tar command to create the folder similar to the tar.gz filename. the answer your refer is to extract to directory already created

Comment: So add the extra step of creating the directory if it doesn't exist.  `mkdir -p filename1; tar xfz filename1.tar.gz -C filename1`.  or with the tarfile's name in a variable: `f='filename1.tgz'; bn="$(basename "$f" ".tgz")"; mkdir -p "$bn"; tar xfz "$f" -C "$bn"`.    If necessary, also use GNU tar's `--transform` or `--strip-components` options to remove any unwanted path elements like `archive_folder/`.  The linked answer provides examples of everything you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

As has been explained in the comments, you can use the answers to [How to choose directory name during untarring](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11018/86440), choosing the directory name to match the archive file name.

Another possibility is to use `unar`; it has a dedicated option for this, `-d`, which will extract the given archive to a directory matching its name.