# Untar file tar compressed file to different directories

Tags: tar, rename, gzip

I have a `.tar.gz` file which may have the following files:

```
folder1/folder2/folder3/imp_folder1/file11.jpg
folder1/folder2/folder3/imp_folder1/file12.jpg
folder1/folder2/folder3/imp_folder2/file21.jpg
folder1/folder2/folder3/imp_folder3/file31.jpg
...
...
```

I want to untar it to the following directories:

```
/new_folder1/new_folder2/imp_folder1/file11.jpg
/new_folder1/new_folder2/imp_folder1/file12.jpg
/new_folder1/new_folder2/imp_folder2/file21.jpg
/new_folder1/new_folder2/imp_folder3/file31.jpg
...
...
```

Basically, `folder1/folder2/folder3/` should be replaced by `/new_folder1/new_folder2/`.

Since, this will have 100s of thousands of files, what will be the fastest way to achieve this ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11020/100397 rather than the accepted/popular answer

Answer (score 2):

You've already got few links to possible answers in the comments, but I wanted to suggest another approach. You can create an identical directory tree as the original in some location, and link the path you want to replace (`folder1/folder2/folder3`) to the new location (`/new_folder1/new_folder2`).

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p folder1/folder2
ln -s /new_folder1/new_folder2 folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Then you can extract the archive by adding the `--keep-directory-symlink` flag (exists since version 1.27).

```
tar --keep-directory-symlink -zxvf tarball.tar.gz
```